# In asp.net dynamic data, how to use UIHint to create a auto-fill field?

Tags: asp.net, templates, field, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm using asp.net dynamic data. There is a field I want to auto fill for users. The file is user name which can be obtained with integrated windows authentication.

I created a Field Template and it works in Insert mode, but in Update mode, once another user updates the record, the new user name should be saved, but it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution and I want to share it.

Apply `UIHint` for the entity field:

```
[UIHint("UserName")]
public object Name { get; set; }
```

Create a a new `FieldTemplate`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" BorderStyle="None"
BackColor="Transparent" Text='<%# FieldValueEditString %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind for `FieldTemplate`:

```
public partial class UserName_EditField : FieldTemplateUserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetUpValidator(RequiredFieldValidator1);    
        EditFieldTemplateUserControl.InsertHelpText(this);
    }

    protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDataBinding(e);

        TextBox1.Visible = true;
    }

    protected string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            var name = this.Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            return name;
        }
    }

    protected override void ExtractValues(IOrderedDictionary dictionary)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {// only assign value when user posts back.
            this.TextBox1.Text = this.UserName.ToUpper();
            dictionary[Column.Name] = ConvertEditedValue(TextBox1.Text);
        }
    }

    public override Control DataControl
    {
        get
        {
            return TextBox1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post answers in the answers section, not as part of the question.